# PHP Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\Socket' not found

Tags: php, class

I also have an error of this type in this simple project..
The structure is:

```
app.php
composer.json
+--app/
   socket.php
+--vendor/
...
```

When I run 'php app.php' I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\Socket' not found in /home/amtek/msgserver/app.php on line 19
```

app.php:

```
<?php
   require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   ...
   use MyApp\Socket;

   $server = IoServer::factory( new HttpServer( new WsServer( new Socket())), 8090 );
   $server->run();
```

./app/socket.php:

```
<?php
 namespace MyApp;

 use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
 use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

 class Socket implements MessageComponentInterface {
 ...
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "MyApp\\": "app"
      }
},
"require": {
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4"
}
}
```

Comment: `socket.js`? Did you run `composer du` (short for `composer dump-autoload`)?

Comment: Sorry, a typo -- socket.php. Yes I run it, nothing changed

Comment: Question: does this stuff work on PHP 5.6.33 ??

Comment: At the moment I inserted #require 'app/socket.php'; and I have no more errors.

Comment: your file name ./app/socket.php should be ./app/Socket.php for autoloader to load class properly